# css() not working with li:before selector

Tags: jquery, css

I have CSS as shown below, Let say if I want to change the border color using jquery for li before it doesn't work for me. Can someone help with this issue. How can I change the color for that css style using Jquery.

```
.multi-steps > li:before {     
  border-color: #ffb22b;
}
```

```js
$('.multi-steps > li:before').css({
  'border-color': '#007bff'
})
```

Comment: please add your html code also.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618941/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery cannot amend pseudo elements as they are not part of the DOM.

To work around this, have jQuery add/remove a class on the element and tie the `:before` CSS rule to that class. For example:

```css
.multi-steps > li:before {     
  border-color: #ffb22b;
}
.multi-steps > li.foo:before {
  border-color: #007bff;
}
```

```js
$('.multi-steps > li').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: If I want to change the color using Jquery then what is the best way?. $('.multi-steps > li.foo').css({'border-color': '#007bff'}); like this?

Comment: No, use the CSS class exactly as in the answer above. You cannot use css() with a psuedo element selector